# How to write a parser for Markup?

Tags: html, parsing, markup

I would like to program a parser for a Markup language similar to BBCode, Markdown, Wikisyntax etc. using a high-level language like Python or Perl. It should feature sectioning, code highlighting, automatic link creation, embedding images but allowing HTML for more complex formatting.

Has anyone done similar things or has worked closely with those systems and could describe generally how this could be done efficiently?
Although efficiency is not really of concern for such a small system, it is generally favourable.
In particular I would like to learn if there is a more efficient way than using regular expressions for such a program.

Comment: Is there a reason *not* to use any of the existing parsers (and languages)? Chances are that you'll run into a lot of problems, corner cases etc. that other people have already experienced (and overcome).

Comment: Sorry, I had my JavaScript off. This question has been asked before and thus can be closed. Although I would have liked a general discussion of the apporoach, this is probably not the place.

Comment: You are free to delete the question without penalty. There are no answers or votes, so it won't disappoint anyone. It's better than wasting everyone's time waiting for it to accumulate close votes, if you are indeed sure that this will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

For your general discussion…

You should start with the following blueprint:

- you need to iterate charwise over entire data
- you need to identify every char by its context, for it may be a tag-opening ('<', '[' etc) or just the char. This may be done by having an escapement flag, triggered by an escape-char (like backslashes in some languages do). if you use that approach, you also need to check for an escaped escapement.
- you may also need some flag telling you to be inside a comment or special data section, that may have different escapement rules.
- you need to build a tree-like structure or at least some stack for nested tags. This is why regexes are a bad idea: they not only take much to much overhead, they're also of no use if you want to get the correct closing tag for the second x (x=any tag) in the following snipped: `<x><x><x></x><x><x></x></x><x></x><!-- </x> -->this one →</x><x></x></x>`